# How to output docker console output when running dgoss tests

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a docker container that is running a python flask/uwsgi application. I am testing the docker container with dgoss by just verifying that a request to localhost returns 200 OK.

```
dgoss run <my-container-name>
```

Of course everything is fine when the test passes. But when it doesn't then I just get for example

```
HTTP: http://localhost:80: status:
Expected
    <int>: 502
to equal
    <int>: 200
```

That can happen if for example the application is importing a package that I forgot to include in the requirements.txt. To debug it I have to start the docker container manually and then it is clear from the console output what the error is. For example:

```
 docker run -p 80:80 <my-container-name>
 ....
 ....
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./main.py", line 11, in <module>
     import pandas as pd
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
 unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
 *** no app loaded. GAME OVER ***
 2020-01-24 08:13:08,940 INFO exited: uwsgi (exit status 22; not expected)
 ...
 ...
```

My question is:
*Is there a way to make dgoss print whatever the docker container prints to it's console? It would really help in debugging when the tests are failing if I could see the flask/uwsgi output.*

Comment: You could use the `CONTAINER_LOG_OUTPUT` param to write the logs from your container in a file.

Comment: Thanks. Was Just looking at that. I cannot find any examples of how to use the param. Do you have an example?

I've tried both to set CONTAINER_LOG_OUTPUT as an environment variable in the container and on the host, but neither worked. I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: I think it should look like `dgoss run <my-container-name> -e CONTAINER_LOG_OUTPUT="/path/to/file.log"`

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for the suggestion @Silveris. 

Still can't get it to work. When I add the 

```-e CONTAINER_LOG_OUTPUT="/path/to/file.log"``` I just get the error ```Error response from daemon: Container 83c26b9aaf1a0bf36d4d5d994e614e2c1ef9201e7e03fe3748df9654c4fcbe4b is not running```. I've modified "/path/to/file.log" to a place on my host running dgoss and the container. I assume that's what I should specify.

Comment: I came up with a workaround. What I do is that if dgoss is failing I'll simply just start the container, print the logs with ```docker logs``` and kill it again. That will at least give me the errors caused by the container not being able to run out of the box. It won't show errors caused when requests are going in.